# quarto file extension not recognized in rstudio

Tags: rstudio, quarto

Trying to start using Quarto together with Rstudio.

Followed the instructions here: https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/rstudio.html

When I run the following commands I obtain:

```
> quarto_version()

[1] ‘1.0.38’

> quarto_path()

[1] "C:\\Users\\jld\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Quarto\\bin\\quarto.cmd"
```

There are no Quarto options in the Global options.

I can't choose Quarto from File or choose it as document type, see images below.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

[image: File meny]

[image: Document type]

Comment: What's your Rstudio version?! Do you have the most recent update?

Comment: RStudio Version 1.3.1093
R version 4.2.1

Comment: Also an additional suggestion, you can use `rstudioapi::versionInfo()` from the [`{rstudioapi}`](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/pkgdown/rstudioapi/index.html) package to get the Rstudio version info nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am understanding from your comment is that you are using an older version of `Rstudio`. From the [`Quarto` Website](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/rstudio.html#overview) it is said that to use `quarto`, we are required to use the **RStudio (v2022.07)**.

So [update your Rstudio version](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download).

Comment: Thanx - so weird - I just updated - but somehow I was using the old version anyway - now it works - great!

Comment: I have done so, but need more rep for it to register.